# Spice model, can't figure it out

Tags: mosfet, spice, modeling, ltspice

I am using LTSpice with the following NMOS model from the library included in the famous book 'Sedra & Smith, Microelectronic circuits' :

```
*       Level-1 Model for the 0.5-um NMOS Transistor (Part NMOS0P5)
*       (created by Anas Hamoui & Olivier Trescases)
.model  NMOS0P5 NMOS(Level=1 VTO=0.7 GAMMA=0.5 PHI=0.8 
+       LD=0.08E-06 WD=0 UO=460 LAMBDA=0.1 TOX=9.5E-9 PB=0.9 CJ=0.57E-3 
+       CJSW=120E-12 MJ=0.5 MJSW=0.4 CGDO=0.4E-9 JS=10E-9 CGBO=0.38E-9
+       CGSO=0.4E-9)
```

Well, to analyze my simulations, I try to make my pencil and paper analysis to notice possible differences.
However, I need to know several things about my MOS, and I can't find the factor ' K = mu_n * C_ox '.
Where should I find it ? Under which name ? I see that often other MOS models for SPICE include this factor in the model definition, which I can't find in the one I am using.

For information, this model, under SPICE, works perfectly well.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Ryl

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/spice.MOSparamlist.html) the default is KP=2E-5. So I would try adding that parameter to the model and seeing if the result changes.

Answer (score 2):

It took some digging, but [I found some definitions](http://web.alfredstate.edu/albaflr/Fall07/ELEC354/LEC%5CMOS%20Circuits%20at%20DC.pdf):

\$ \mu_n \$ is the electron mobility, which is \$ 1360 \frac{cm^2}{Vs} \$

\$ C_{ox} \$ is the capacitance per unit area of the oxide layer, which is \$ \dfrac {\epsilon_{ox}}{t_{ox}} \$

\$ {\epsilon_{ox}} = 3.45 \times 10^{-11} \frac{F}{m} \$

\$ t_{ox} \$ is the thickness of the oxide layer.

The only unknown appears to be the thickness of the oxide layer, which is already in your model (TOX = 9.5E-9), so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are some of method to calculate:
$$k=\mu_n\times C_{ox}$$

Example: parameter extraction for more accuracy:
Calculate: Vth & K of MOSFET
[image]